# How to remove redundant output

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sum, compare

My problem is this: 
"Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k.

For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17."

And wrote this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>

template<int N>

bool adding(int (&list)[N], int k) {

    //get size of array
    int length = (sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]));
    std::cout << k << std::endl;
    bool a = false;

    //init 2 pointer on array
    int *p1;
    p1 = &list[0];

    int *p2;
    p2 = &list[0];

    int sum = 0;

    int lengthNew = length;

    //check if p1+p2 = k
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < lengthNew; j++) {
            sum = *p1 + *p2;

            if (p1 == p2) {
                p2++;
                j++;                
            }
            else if (sum == k) {
                std::cout << sum << " = " << k  << "\t*p1= " <<*p1<<"\t*p2= "<< *p2 << std::endl;
                a = true;
            }
            p2++;
        }
        p2 = p2 - length;
        p1++;

    }

    return a;

}

int main() {

    int myInts[] = { 19,1,2,18,13,4,10,5,5,12,7,10,8,16 };
    int k = 21;

    adding(myInts, k);

    int w;  
    std::cin >> w;

    return 0;

}
```

I get this output:

```
21 = 21 *p1= 19 *p2= 2
21 = 21 *p1= 2  *p2= 19

21 = 21 *p1= 13 *p2= 8

21 = 21 *p1= 5  *p2= 16
21 = 21 *p1= 5  *p2= 16

21 = 21 *p1= 8  *p2= 13

21 = 21 *p1= 16 *p2= 5
21 = 21 *p1= 16 *p2= 5
```

As you can see there are always two equal outputs. I know that it's because I am settin p2 back to the beginning, but I don't know how to do it otherwise. Could someone show me how to bypass the redundant information? I thought that i could save the addresses of the outputs and compare if this combination is already used. But I think it's not a good solution.

Comment: add the last output to stream. before printing compare with the previous. If not same print..

Comment: remove duplicates from the array before you run your algorithm

Comment: How do you mean by adding the last output to stream? @kelalaka

Comment: @user463035818 why should they? if `k` is `10`, `5+5` would be a valid case

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/ store it like ostream, compare with str()

Comment: @kelalaka but the problem is that if I my array looks like this: {19,19,2,2} it would only print it once with the stream. But in this case it should print it twice.

Comment: @S.Yildiz With `{19,19,2,2}` shouldn't it print 4 times? There are 4 pairs of elements which sum up to 21. If we assume the array elements `{a,b,c,d}`, the pairs are `{a,c}, {a,d}, {b,c}, {b,d}`

Comment: [OT]: your algorithm is `O(n²)`, whereas, once you sort your input (`O(n log n)`), you might find pairs in linear complexity (resulting in final `O(n log n)`)

Answer (score 3):

Because addition is commutative, you don't have to go through the whole array for every element.
It's enough to check all the elements *after* the element you're currently checking.

```
bool adding(const std::vector<int>& list, int k) {
    bool result = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            int sum = list[i] + list[j];
            if (sum == k) {
                std::cout << sum << " = " << k  << "\tn1= " <<list[i]<<"\tn2= "<< list[j] << std::endl;
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Each pair of elements will be only compared once now.

Comment: As a side note, I changed array passed by reference to a `std::vector`, as it's preferable at almost every occasion. You could still use array, but vector does all the hard work for you :)

Comment: p1 and p2 should be list[i] and list[j]?

Comment: please check your print line